# flex-direction seems to be not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a website that uses this one for a long time, but somehow a few weeks or months ago it stopped working properly.

```
<div class="content-label inputIconBg">
   <input class="content-input" required type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="cost" placeholder="Cost" />
    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cost" data-placement="left"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

```
.content-label {
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

Before, the icons are on the left side inside the box. Now I'm not sure what went wrong.
I had to remove the flex-direction: row-reverse; for the icons to show up, if I don't do that, that icons are totally gone.

[image]

What do you think happened?

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working fine.

Comment: @Aman it seems like it's broken on Chrome-based browsers.

Comment: You have only z-index issue

Comment: add this css in style.css    .content-label.inputIconBg i {
    z-index: 1;
}

Comment: Oh dang, that fixed it, bro. Thanks so much. I'm not sure why that happened. Can you please create that an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: okay, I have posted answer please mark thanks @foxseiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index to fix this issue.

```
.content-label.inputIconBg i { 
     z-index: 1; 
}
```